# Azure Devops: Notification on creation of a new branch

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to have a notification when a new branch has been created? I couldn't see it in the service hooks section.

What I'm trying to achieve is: when a user creates a branch a notification is sent out and upon recieving this event I create some external things.

I think I could get round this by listening for work item updates if the branch is created from the work item and get the link from that, but I'd have to ensure users relate branches and work items.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DevOps doesn't have such built-in feature.

But you can use below YAML to send notifications:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - refs/heads/*
    exclude:
    - refs/heads/main

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:

- task: SendEmail@1
  inputs:
    To: 'xxx@xxx.com'
    From: 'xxx@xxx.com'
    Subject: 'xxx'
    Body: 'xxx'
    BodyAsHtml: false
    AddAttachment: false
    SmtpServer: 'smtp.xxx.com'
    SmtpPort: '587'
    SmtpUsername: 'xxx@xxx.com'
    SmtpPassword: 'xxx'
```

Successful:

[image]

[image]

Please notice to remove the related yml of the above pipeline in the branch or disable the trigger in it after you create the branch, this is to prevent the changes in old branches from triggering the above pipeline.